# How to fit a curve to data in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression, newtons-method

Alright, my second question on this topic. I already asked a similar question and tried to implement different solutions, but nothing seems to work. Kinda sad if you think about it.

To tell you what this is about: I am trying to fit a function of the form `y=a+b*log(c(x-d)) to a set of data. The data set is quite large and is listed below:

```
x y
2 36
4 44
6 47
8 45
10 47
12 49
14 46
16 44
18 47
20 50
22 51
24 49
26 51
28 53
30 57
32 54
34 55
36 54
38 56
40 57
42 58
44 55
46 57
48 57
50 57
52 56
54 59
56 57
58 56
60 56
62 58
64 59
66 57
68 57
70 58
72 58
74 59
76 57
78 57
80 57
82 58
84 58
86 57
88 58
90 57
100 60
110 58
120 59
130 59
140 60
150 59
160 60
170 60
180 61
600 61
900 59
1200 61
1500 61
1800 63
2700 62
3600 63
4500 63
5400 64
```

Since I am an absolute beginner in R (I literally started working with this language 2 days ago), I have developed a fairly rudamentary script that I thought was good. Here is is:

```
dat <- read.table(text= "x y 
2 36
4 44
6 47
8 45
10 47
12 49
14 46
16 44
18 47
20 50
22 51
24 49
26 51
28 53
30 57
32 54
34 55
36 54
38 56
40 57
42 58
44 55
46 57
48 57
50 57
52 56
54 59
56 57
58 56
60 56
62 58
64 59
66 57
68 57
70 58
72 58
74 59
76 57
78 57
80 57
82 58
84 58
86 57
88 58
90 57
100 60
110 58
120 59
130 59
140 60
150 59
160 60
170 60
180 61
600 61
900 59
1200 61
1500 61
1800 63
2700 62
3600 63
4500 63
5400 64", header = TRUE)
model <- nls(y ~ a * log(x) + c, data = dat, start = list(a=1, c=0))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(size = 5) +
    stat_smooth(method = nlm, formula = as.formula(model[[1]]), method.args = list(start = list(a = 2,c = 3)), size = 1, se = FALSE, color = "orange", linetype = 2)
```

Nothing seems to work though, there is always an error message saying

```
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
Argument "p" is missing without default
```

You see, usually I would try to figure this out myself somehow. However, the issue that I am facing now is that I have very little experience in R and have no idea what most of these objects actually mean. Most of this code is just a 12th grade high school student showing off his excellent copy&paste skills. This is why it would be great if anyone here could help me out constructing a script that would help me plot the function mentioned above to these datapoints. It does not necessarily matter if the starting values you come up with make the values converge, all that matters at this point is that I have a script that tells me the parameters and fits a curve to the datapoints.

Thanks a lot in advance! Your help is greatly appreciated and would help me out in despair.

Comment: I think your `stat_smooth` should look more like `stat_smooth(method = "nls", formula = formula(model), method.args = list(start = list(a = 2,c = 3)), size = 1, se = FALSE, color = "orange", linetype = 2)` in this case. Note that the `method="nls"` rather than `method=nlm` and there was no need for the `[[1]]` when choosing the formula from the model.

Comment: I am still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: I am unable to replicate that error. Test with `ggplot2_3.2.1` and `R version 3.6.0`. Make sure you are testing in a clean R environment. Perhaps update your package if using an older version.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your tip! Could you also tell me how I can find out the parameters of the function?